# Is there a way to get python scripts working on ubuntu server?

Tags: python

my problem is, that I wrote some python scripts, which are working fine. Now I have to get them to work on an ubuntu server. The problem is, that I need to use the chromedriver (selenium) and ofc there cant be an open browser at the server. So is there a way to use selenium with a server?

Comment: Any packages you've installed locally for your scripts to work, should be also installed on the server.

Comment: But the script needs a file on the clients desktop. The chromedriver, the chromedriver cant work on a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is called 'Headless' editions of a browser.

These headless browsers don't open up as a browser but run in the background for you to perform scripts on.

Try searching for Headless + 'The browser driver you use'

Here is a quick tutorial to get you started: https://medium.com/@pyzzled/running-headless-chrome-with-selenium-in-python-3f42d1f5ff1d